# Touch screen zoom/scroll on fabric.js canvas

Tags: javascript, touch, fabricjs

I'm trying to create a small web app using Javascript and `fabric.js` (the latest version downloaded yesterday from GitHub).
I'd like to have that application usable both on mobile devices and on the desktop.

What I need is a canvas where I can place a few movable shapes, nothing too difficult. The problem is that it looks like it's impossible to obtain this result on mobile devices while being still able to freely move around in the canvas using touch gestures.
I was previously working with version 1.7, and with that version moving objects would result in the page scrolling at the same time making really hard to control the movement of the shape (like if the `fabric.js` listener didn't block the event propagation).

So I updated it to the last version and, no matter what I do, the browser will ignore zoom and pan over the canvas area (the problem is, in fact, the opposite now).

I think I have tried more or less everything, starting from:

```
allowTouchScrolling = true / false;
```

To manually overriding (using both `!important` and a jQuery solution) the inline canvas style added from `fabric.js` thinking that it was the cause of the problem, with no luck.

```
touch-action: none; -> touch-action: manipulation;
```

Finally, what I'd like to see is a canvas where I can both drag the shapes on (with the events being prevented from propagating from fabric) and move in the page using gestures (not over movable shapes, of course).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Fabric doesn't support zoom/panning with any controls by default. You'll need to implement the tooling that will move the fabric canvas. The touch controls built into fabric are for moving and modifying the shapes.